# Processing 2 List in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I have some data, like this:

```
let id = [11;9;12];;
let student = [(9, "ann"); (10, "ben"); (11, "carl"); (12, "dave")];;
```

Please help me to implement a function called getName
In example

```
> getName(id, student);;
- ["carl";"ann";"dave"]
```

Comment: Have you attepmpted to write `getName` yourself? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: Fixed some spelling and removed irrelevant thanks.

Comment: First write a function that takes only one id and the student list and returns the name with that id. Then write a function that uses the first function for each id. (You'll use recursion in both functions.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning functional programming, then the right approach would be to use recursion. But to help you with that, you'll need to share the code that you tried to write.

In practice, the easiest option is probably to turn the list into a dictionary using the `dict` function and then lookup all IDs in the dictionary:

```
let getStudents ids students = 
  let lookup = dict students
  ids |> List.map (fun id -> lookup.[id])

getStudents id student
```